# How to draw vertical line (ie: x = some values)?

Tags: pchart

I'm drawing a time series chart.

[image]

I need to draw vertical line at every start of month. How I do it using pChart 2.0? I read the documentation but didn't found any function to do it.

Answer (score 0):

pChart2 allows you draw different kind of charts in same chart. So you can draw bar chart in same chart above, by having value at the first point of each month. And put in VOID for the rest of points.